# LINQ Performance Issue: Sum Takes Longer with Fewer Records

Tags: linq, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-entities, wcf-ria-services

Silverlight 4 app using WCF RIA Services

I have a page with a ComboBox and a TabControl. Each TabItem has a usercontrol that displays a RAD Chart control. The ComboBox contains items that are used to filter the data that the user controls display in the charts. When the ComboBox selection changes, the page updates a collection of entities held on a property of a instance/singleton class. The user controls are notified of the change, and they access the updated collection of entities to give to the chart control. It all works. When the ComboBox selection changes, the usercontrols display a subset of the data chosen based on the ComboBox selected item.

What has me confused is the time it takes to iterate through the collection of entities while preparing the values that are handed to the chart control. The chart displays 12 months of data, so I iterate the collection 12 times and use a LINQ query to get a Sum on a property of the objects in the collection. I have isolated the performance issue to the single LINQ query that performs the Sum:

```
Decimal sum = myCollection.Where(m => m.CreationDate.Month == month).Sum(m => (m.SalePrice ?? 0));
```

That single line of code can sometimes take more than a second to run. That's not horrible, but I am iterating 12 months, so that line of code is run 12 times.

Here is the kicker...

The top ComboBox option is 'all records'. So in my test example, the first time the line of code above is used to get a 'Sum', the collection has 500+ records. It returns the Sum in .2 seconds. I change the ComboBox to a selection that filters the results down so the collection has only 80 records in it. Mind you, it is not a totally different set of records, it is just a subset of the 500 that meet another criteria. The line of code above takes 1.2 seconds to run. **When I ask for a sum from 500+ records, it takes .2 seconds. When I ask for a sum from 80 records, it takes 1.2 seconds.**

What could cause this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you filter to create the subset?  Is "Collection" a Linq query itself, that is deffered in execution until this line?  If so, the speed difference you are seeing could be the application of the filtering logic.

One general possibility for making this faster would be to compute all 12 numbers in a single pass.  That is easy enough by using the GroupBy Linq operator:

```
var AllSums = Collection.GroupBy(m=>m.CreationData.Month).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(m => m.SalePrice ?? 0));
var JanuarySum = AllSums[January];
```

This should outperform 12 completely separate loops.

Edit:
Here is a good description of deferred execution: [Linq and Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Comment: I call it a subset, because I want to emphasize that it is not a totally different 80 records, but rather just 80 records from the initial 500.

I see what you mean by potential of the filter being deferred until execution of this line. Here is where my LINQ understanding stops. If I do a Count() on the collection (as I am before the pasted line above), and it yeilds 80 records, will the same filter be performed again every time I sum against the collection?

Comment: Uhg.. keep hitting enter before I am done typing my comment... To create the collection, I am creating a new IEnumerable<MyObjectType> and setting it equal to another collecion.Where( ... and a few other where clauses. Is this new instance of a collection have potential delayed execution on the where clauses? The first time you query the collection, if it was deferred, will it be deferred every time you query it? Thanks... 

And I will be trying out your GroupBy clause, after I understand the perf issue.

Comment: If I create a new collection and populate it using a LINQ query from another collection, are there any delayed execution concerns on the new collection?

Comment: Chris, I used yoru example to creat a var that holds yoru groupby statement above. Now, the full 1.2 second delay still exists, and it happens when I get the value from the var:

sum = var.Where(o >= o.Month == month).First().sum;

Comment: adding to that last comment... the reason that 1.2 sec delay is still a problem, is that I still have to get the values for each of the 12 months from: sum = var.Where(o >= o.Month == month).First().sum;

Comment: @Roger Guess: Yes, if "collection" is the result of calling "Where" several times, then it is only a query object that has not been executed.  Every time you perform an operation that actually *returns* the data (count, sum, first, foreach, etc), the query will be executed.  If you need to lookup all the results by month, add a ToLookup that produces the lookup at the end of the query.  ToLookup will execute the query only once.  I will add this to the answer.